# Reading in data with different column lengths and spaces in R

Tags: r

I have data that looks something like this:

```
category 2011 2012 2013 2104
word word word 15,000.11 1,000.15 13,001.50 20,000,001.52
word 2,000.120 400,000.00 57,000.523 402,000,111
word word 4,000.120 455,000.02 57,600.87 403,000,111.18
word 2,056.120 678,000.00 670,000.523 402,009,111.65
```

It is in a .csv file. I want to read it in so it separates into columns but they are all different lengths so I am not sure how. I know I can separate by spaces but some of the words in the first column have spaces between them.

```
category         2011      2012         2013         2104
word word word  15,000.11  1,000.15    13,001.50    20,000,001.52
word            2,000.120  400,000.00  57,000.523   402,000,111
word word       4,000.120  455,000.02  57,600.87    403,000,111.18
word            2,056.120  678,000.00  670,000.523  402,009,111.65
```

I apologize if I am not asking this correctly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can make the delimiter with `sub` after reading the dataset with `readLines`

```
lines[-1] <- sub("^([A-Za-z ]+)(?=\\s[0-9])", "'\\1'", lines[-1], perl = TRUE)
read.table(textConnection(lines), header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
#      category      2011       2012        2013           2104
#1 word word word 15,000.11   1,000.15   13,001.50  20,000,001.52
#2           word 2,000.120 400,000.00  57,000.523    402,000,111
#3      word word 4,000.120 455,000.02   57,600.87 403,000,111.18
#4           word 2,056.120 678,000.00 670,000.523 402,009,111.65
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines('file.csv')
```

Comment: I am getting an error that says "incomplete file line found", any ideas?

Comment: @alex it is not an error, just a warning.  Don;'t worry about that.  check the `lines`

Comment: Oh okay its saying "line 1 did not have 11 elements" is there somewhere that you are specifying the length?

Comment: @alex is it on the same example you showed, because I didn't get that error.

Comment: no it's different some of the values for the first column have several words

Comment: @alex can you update with that example giving the issue or use `fill = TRUE` in `read.table`